# Splitting Result of query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have an application using html, javascript w/jquery and php in the server side. The application sends `$.ajax()` requisitions to the server (php files) that then returns to me a result.

What happens, it's that I have a very big sql query that it's taking too long to load because of the number of rows returned and because some conversions that I have to do to them.

**How can I split this big query in small others?**

Or **how can I do a small query, show it results then do another query that begins from the position that the other stopped?**(without duplicating the results).

ps: I already tried `array_chunk` but it wont't worked. It's shows me the same number of rows. When I tried to show via javascript, it returns me as *undefined*

Here is a fragment of code:(.php)

```
//I made the connetion and all the queries using PDO
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4 FROM table WHERE st <> 'C-CONDITION' ");
    $sql->execute();

    $result = $sql->fetchAll();

    $answer['dt'] = $r;     
    //here i'm sending the result to the client(javascript) on JSON format.
    echo json_encode($retorno,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: you can search about a topic called pagination / limit offset, don't use `array_chunk`, you'll just cut the array in bunches but that will still load em all up

Comment: No, that won't do, I need to load just a piece. Then in javascript, as the user needs, I'll send more requisitions loading the rest

Comment: that won't do? which one? just limit it to 10 or whatever then adjust the offset accordingly, pass it along in your request in your ajax

Comment: I think not, see, I want, for example,  that from a database where I have the numbers 1,2,3,4,5, one query shows me 1,3,5 and the other 2,4. Nearly about this.

Comment: @RodrigoDuterte thanks man, searching here I figured it out that you were right. I can do it using limit and offset in php query. After I finish it I will post my answer here. Thanks.